# How to draw a histogram with ncurses?

Tags: c, histogram, ncurses

I have a code that reads from input, counts letters and draws a histogram as ASCII art. I would like to do the same but with ncurses. How to do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  int c, i, j;
  int chars[256];
  // a counter for every character in the ASCII set
  for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    chars[i] = 0;
  }
  // check each input and increment the relative element
  while ((c = getchar()) != '0') {
    ++chars[c];
  }
  // print only those characters that were received
  for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    // go through every element in chars
    if (chars[i] > 0) {
      // print headers
      if (i == ' ')
        printf(" Space: ");
      else if (i == '\n')
        printf("    \\n: ");
      else if (i == '\t')
        printf("   tab: ");
      else
        printf("%6c: ", i);
      for (j = 0; j < chars[i]; ++j)
        // print a # for every tally of each element; chars[i] is the tally
        putchar('#');
        // and we need to go through each from 0 to the final tally of that element
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Side note: the ASCII range is 0..127

Comment: What do you want from curses?  You could use the same format although there are potentially too many lines to fit in the window.  The bars of the histogram could be draw as characters or lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CDK Histogram](http://invisible-island.net/cdk/manpage/cdk_histogram.3.html) from the Curses Development Kit. It's super easy; [here](http://pastebin.com/tnWvKux6) is an exemplary code demonstrating the usage (taken from the Debian libcdk package).

Comment: Eh, that example shows how to draw 3 independent bars. The CDK histogram isn't really a histogram. i.e. a chart of distribution acrossed binned intervals. Its a mechanism for drawing a bar based on a value but doesnt do any of the "binning" or distribution logic. Its also not even a bar chart with mulitple values. Its just a bar widget.